# Split into 3 characters in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a string value in db. I need to insert a `,` in between each 3 characters. Here is the example string.

**Sample String**

```
111100120125     // This sample is a dynamic string. So It can be less or more ..
```

**Result**

```
Val = 111,100,120,125
```

Please tell me about the builtin SqlServer function to get the `,` seperated string as a result.

Any help to this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just a single string variable or table field? and is there a maximum possible length defined in field/variable?

Comment: I think the best course is to create a CLR UDF -- unless the possible values are a very narrow range.

Comment: Its a table value and Its varchar(200) type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE:

```
declare @f varchar(100)='111100120125'
;with pos as(
select 3 n, cast(SUBSTRING(@f,1,3) as varchar(max)) a
union all
select n+3 n, a+','+ SUBSTRING(@f,n+1,3) from pos
where n<LEN(@f)
)
select max(@f) ini, max(a) res from pos;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me about the builtin SqlServer function to get the ,
>   seperated string as a result.

You can use **[Stuff()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)** function. **[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22612)** specific to your given string.

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = '111100120125'

SELECT STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@S,4,0,','),8,0,','),12,0,',')

111,100,120,125
```

**EDIT:** More generic solution would be to create a function like below (Note that this function starts inserting separator value from end):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AddSeparator (@String VARCHAR(max), @Separator VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Length int = Len(@String)
    WHILE (@Length > 3)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @String = STUFF(@String, @Length - 2, 0, @Separator),
           @Length = @Length -3
    END

    RETURN @String
END;
```

Usage and **[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/398b0/1)** :

```
SELECT String Original, dbo.AddSeparator(String, ',') Modified
FROM T
```

Results:

```
| ORIGINAL |  MODIFIED |
|----------|-----------|
|          |           |
|        1 |         1 |
|       12 |        12 |
|      123 |       123 |
|     1234 |     1,234 |
|    12345 |    12,345 |
|   123456 |   123,456 |
|  1234567 | 1,234,567 |
```

Comment: The string `111100120125` can be dynamic. So I want to know for dynamic level of string seperation.